# Remove Commas and Speech Marks When Writing to a Text File

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, text-files

I want to write the contents of a multidimensional array into a text file and remove the commas and speech marks and also space the contents out to form a table-like structure. Here is my code and the array:

"booklist" is a multidimensional list that stores data from a text file (this part of my code works).

```
file = open('database.txt', 'r')
booklist = []
for line in file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    line_list = stripped_line.split()
    booklist.append(line_list)
file.close()


with open('database2.txt', 'w') as f:
    for listitem in booklist:
        f.write('%s\n' % listitem)
f.close()
```

This is a screenshot of the text file that gets written to the list:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iZ3J.png

Comment: Just use in your second last line:  **listitem.replace('"','').replace(',','')**

Comment: @MarcelSonderegger I tried this but I get an attribute error saying: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Ah, then it is not a string yet:  it is a list in a list. Just **print (listitem)** bevore the error happens and you will see. Your command **split** produces also a list.

Comment: @MarcelSonderegger Thank you, I was able to solve my problem using "listitem = '\t\t'.join(booklist[i])"